# Synonymize [bad-request] and [400-bad-request] to [http-status-code-400]

Tags: support, tags, synonym-request

Both [bad-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bad-request)(x598) and [http-status-code-400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-400)(x732) refer to the same issue and is better synonymized. I believe they're better left as synonyms without being merged, as bad-request is the official name  associated with the status code 400. But if merging can still keep the [bad-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bad-request) name, then that is preferred.

---

New tag [400-bad-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/400-bad-request)(x46) created by someone. Needs merging/synonymizing.

Comment: If they're synonyms, why not merge them? Can you provide more explanation?

Comment: @CodyGray I thought(but I'm not sure) merging [bad-request] to [http-status-400] would remove [bad-request] completely. So, if new users get a [bad-request] error, they'll just add back this tag. But if it remains a synonym, then even if [bad-request] is added, it'll automatically be retagged to [https-status-code-400].

Comment: A mod can merge _and_ create a synonym. They're not mutually exclusive operations.